# How to start FAYE (capistrano deploy) in EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, capistrano, faye

I have an app in an Amazon EC2 server.
The app uses FAYE to work with websocket.
When I run the command in the EC2 console:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rackup private_pub.ru -o 0.0.0.0 -s thin -p 9292 -E production
```

The app works fine.
But it is started manually.

I need to put this to start in the capistrano deploy.

My setup:

```
OS: Linux Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Ruby -v: 2.2.2p95
Rails -v: 4.2.1
Capistrano lock: 3.5.0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Connect in your EC2 server via SSH and navigate to your rails root folder
2. Execute this command `tmux new -s faye`
3. Execute this command `RAILS_ENV=production rackup private_pub.ru -o 0.0.0.0 -s thin -p 9292 -E production`
4. Type `Ctrl+b` and next type `d`

It will start a faye process in your server.

To see the process that are running in port 9292, execute the command:

```
lsof -i :9292
```

#### More info

1. About [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/). You must to install tmux in your server.
2. [How to enable port 9292 to faye in EC2](http://thelazylog.com/running-faye-server-on-aws-elasticbeanstalk-with-load-balancer). See in [cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:5jrpigFR978J:thelazylog.com/running-faye-server-on-aws-elasticbeanstalk-with-load-balancer/%20&cd=9&hl=pt-BR&ct=clnk&gl=br)